# Bootsratp-4 Servlet bean data

Tags: java, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a JSP with a dropdown that the values are populated from a bean that was generated at the backend.

Issue : The jsp is loading without populating the data first time but if I refresh the screen second time, then the dropdown is getting filled. How can I force HTML/Bootstratp-4/Jquery to wait till the data is ready ? Thanks!

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label for="reportingYear">Reporting Year</label>
<select class="form-control" id="reportingYear" name="reportingYear" required >
 <c:forEach var="reportingYear" items="${reportingYears}">
   <option value="${reportingYear.reportingYearValue}" >${reportingYear.reportingYearDesc}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please select Reporting Year.
  </div>                              
 </div>
```

Comment: what are you using for your MVC framework ? Or you are using just Servlet JSP ?

Comment: Servlet/JSP/POJO